# Multiple nested for loops

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am programming in Mathematica and I am trying to avoid multiple for loops.

Let n be a given integer and f a function which takes an n-tuple. Given the bound k, I am looking for an efficient way to loop over all n-tuples where each entry ranges from -k to k. (I would be plugging the n-tuples in to f.)

I tried Mathematica's function Tuples[Range[-k,k],n] except I quite often want n to be around 8, 10, or even 15, and even with k as small as 2, (I would like k to be at least 4 or 5) the memory will run out trying to hold (2k+1)^n tuples.

I originally used n for loops, and it did work. Now I want to vary n, and I can't keep manually going in and inserting code for each n.

Thanks for any help and advice you can give!

Comment: In general, if you need a variable nested loop depth, you should look into recursion.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to programatically build up nested loops:

```
ftup[tup_] := Print[tup]
n = 2
k = 1
Do @@ Join[{Unevaluated[ftup[Array[ a, n]]]}, 
      Table[ { a[i], -k, k } , {i, n }]]
```

This shows we are replicating the built in tuples:

```
ftup[tup_] := Sow[tup];
n = 6;
k = 3;
Last@Last@Reap[ Do @@ 
 Join[{Unevaluated[ftup[Array[ a, n]]]},Table[ { a[i], -k, k } , {i, n }]]  ]
    ==  Tuples[ Range[-k, k] , {n}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need one loop. Here's one that prints all necessary tuples for you:

```
With[{k = 2, n = 3}, Do[Print[IntegerDigits[i, 2 k + 1, n] - k], {i, 0, (2 k + 1)^n - 1}]];
```